# Karma + Jasmine + JSONFixtures: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

**Background:**

I am trying to write unit tests for my javascript jsonTransformer, which transforms JSON-Schema to project specific JSON.

As first test i want to have a blackbox test for this transformer, which receives the input-JSON and compares the transformed JSON to the correct JSON.

I am using Karma and Jasmine as test environment.

**Problem:**

How do I solve the following error?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined
at jasmine.JSONFixtures.loadFixtureIntoCache_ (.../node_modules/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js:257:6)
at jasmine.JSONFixtures.getFixtureData_ (.../node_modules/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js:249:41)
at jasmine.JSONFixtures.read (.../node_modules/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js:238:12)
at jasmine.JSONFixtures.proxyCallTo_ (.../node_modules/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js:272:29)
at window.getJSONFixture (.../node_modules/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js:836:38)
at Object.<anonymous> (...test/test.js:24:8)
at Object.e [as invoke] (.../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js:39:394)
at Object.workFn (.../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2439:20)
```

**Structure:**

ALL dependencies are in "./node-modules/".
The karma.config is in "./node-modules/karma/".

The index.html is in "./app/".
The JS-Files are in "./app/js/".

The test.js is in "./test/".
The JSON mocks are in "./test/mock/".

**Code:**

karma.config:

```
basePath: '../..',

frameworks: ['jasmine'],

files: [
    'node_modules/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js',
    'node_modules/angular/angular.min.js',
    'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'app/js/formulargenerator.js',
    'app/js/*.js',
    'test/*.js',

    // fixtures
    {pattern: 'test/mock/*.json', watched: true, served: true, included: false}
],
```

test.js:

```js
describe('jsonTransformer', function() {
 var $httpBackend, scope;

 beforeEach(inject(function ($injector, $rootScope, $controller) {
     jasmine.getJSONFixtures().fixturesPath='base/test/mock';

  dump(jasmine.getJSONFixtures());
  dump(getJSONFixture('mock_formularSpecification.json'));

  $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
     $httpBackend.whenGET('http://localhost:8080/myProject/rest/form/1').respond(
         getJSONFixture('mock_input.json')
     );

     scope = $rootScope.$new();
     $controller('jsonTransformer', {'$scope': scope});
     dump($controller);
 }));

 var transformedJSON = getJSONFixture('mock_output.json'); //todo: transform

 it('should have transformed the input-JSON to the correct output-JSON', function() {
  $httpBackend.flush();
     expect(transformedJSON).toBe(getJSONFixture('mock_angularFormly.json'));
 });

});
```

Comment: Could it be because jquery is not loaded as a test dependency?

Comment: Yes, sadly that was the problem. I installed jquery via npm but I forgot to list it in the karma.conf file:
'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Chanthu for pointing out my missing dependency: jquery

I installed jquery via npm but I forgot to list it in the karma.conf file: 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',